# InputStream for CSV exporter

Tags: java, io

I have following method:

```
public String exportAsCsv(CqlQuery query) {
    Iterator<String> result = queryService.execute(.....);
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (String nextLine : result) {
       buf.append(nextLine);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

It executes some query which returns `Iterator<String>` - it contains gigabytes of data, so appending it to `StringBuilder` is not the best idea...

I would like to change my method so that it returns `InputStream` instead.

This could be one possible implementation (pseudo code):

```
public InputStream exportAsCsv(CqlQuery query) {
    final Iterator<String> result = queryService.execute(query,false);
    return new MagicalInputStream(){
            @Overwrite
            byte[] readNext() {
                if(!result.hasNext()) { 
                   return null; 
                 } else { 
                   return result.next().getBytes();
                 }
            }       
    }
}
```

I am looking for `InputStream` where I have to implement abstract method (like `byte[] readNext()`), which will be used to read data chunks - one by one. So this input stream has to buffer read chunk, stream it back, and when its buffer is empty it should read next chunk. 
The idea is, that I read next elements from Iterator ONLY when "client" rads next bytes from input stream.

Or there might be another possibility to change my method so that it does return `InputStream` instead of `String` - any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole `InputStream` implementation could be avoided if you allow your method to accept an `java.io.Writer`. Instead of appending Strings to the in-memory `StringBuilder`, you append them to the provided Writer.

```
public void exportAsCsv(CqlQuery query, Writer writer) {
    Iterator<String> result = queryService.execute(.....);
    for (String nextLine : result) {
        writer.append(nextLine);
    }
}
```

If you really want an InputStream, though, you could try something like this:

```
public InputStream exportAsCsv(CqlQuery query) {
    Iterator<String> result = queryService.execute(.....);
    return new SequenceInputStream(asStreamEnum(result));
}   

private Enumeration<InputStream> asStreamEnum(final Iterator<String> it) {
    return new Enumeration<InputStream>() {

        @Override
        public boolean hasMoreElements() {
            return it.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream nextElement() {
            try {
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(it.next().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

    };
}
```

I haven't actually tested this approach yet, so be warned; conceptually, though, I think this is what you're after.

Comment: Thank you - SequenceInputStream was the class I was looking for!